# Upload files to SQL Server 2008 database using MS Access 2010

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I need to load files eg excel, word etc documents to SQL Server 2008 so that they can be viewable/downloadable from a website. I need to be able to load and open the files from the access database and website.

Can anyone help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it in an old project. You can strip away the progress bar stuff and some of the other stuff but you get the idea

```
Public Sub Upload_file_OLD(lMaterial_ID As Long, strFile_name As String)
'upload the file to the selected material ID.
Dim adStream As ADODB.Stream
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
On Error GoTo Error_trap

'check if we have an open connection, if we do use it
Select Case dbCon.State
    Case adStateOpen
        'connection is open, do nothing
    Case adStateConnecting
        'still conecting wait
        Do Until dbCon.State = adStateOpen
            Application.Echo True, "Connection to DB"
        Loop
    Case adStateClosed
        'connection closed, try to open it
        If Len(strSQL_con_string) = 0 Then
            Set_SQL_con "MCTS"
        End If
        dbCon.ConnectionString = strSQL_con_string
        dbCon.Provider = "sqloledb"
        dbCon.Open
End Select

Me.acxProg_bar.Value = 0
Me.acxProg_bar.Visible = True
Me.Repaint

Set adStream = New ADODB.Stream
adStream.Type = adTypeBinary
adStream.Open
Me.acxProg_bar.Value = 10
Me.Repaint
adStream.LoadFromFile strFile_name
Me.acxProg_bar.Value = 50
Me.Repaint

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT Material_FS,Material_file_name, Material_size FROM tblMaterials WHERE Material_ID=" & lMaterial_ID, dbCon, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
Me.acxProg_bar.Value = 60
Me.Repaint
Me.txtFile_size = adStream.Size
rst.Fields("Material_FS").Value = adStream.Read
rst.Fields("Material_file_name").Value = GetFileName(strFile_name)
rst.Fields("Material_size").Value = adStream.Size
Me.acxProg_bar.Value = 90
Me.Repaint
rst.Update
rst.Close
dbCon.Close
Me.acxProg_bar.Value = 0
Me.acxProg_bar.Visible = False
Me.Repaint


Exit Sub

Error_trap:

If dbCon Is Nothing = False Then
    If dbCon.State = adStateOpen Then dbCon.Close
End If

DoCmd.Hourglass False
MsgBox "An error happened in sub Upload_file, error description, " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "MCTS"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the above code to work, but I did get this to work.  SQL Server blob field is varbinary(max).

Upload:

```
Sub TestDocUpload()
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim st As New ADODB.Stream

st.Type = adTypeBinary
st.Open
st.LoadFromFile "c:\temparea\18572.pdf"

With cmd
    .CommandText = "Insert into tbldocuments(docblob, doctype) values (?, ?)"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P1", adLongVarBinary, adParamInput, st.Size, st.Read)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "CustPO")

End With
If cnlocal.State = 0 Then OpenNewLocalConnection
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnlocal
cmd.Execute

End Sub
```

Retrieve:

```
Sub TestReadDoc()
Dim myblob() As Byte
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

If cnlocal.State = 0 Then OpenNewLocalConnection
rs.Open "tblDocuments", cnlocal, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
rs.MoveFirst
myblob = rs!DocBlob
Open "c:\temparea\output.pdf" For Binary Access Write As 1
Put #1, , myblob
Close #1

End Sub
```